# Setting a Session Variable

Tags: php, session

Wonder if someone could help me. I am trying to set a session variable from a database table. Essentially what I need to do is when someone logs in, it takes the value from the 'user_group' column of the user table for the user that has logged in and assign it to the session variable. At the moment it is just passing in the username which is manually typed in by the user upon login.

This is my current code for login.php. I have tried various things and looked on here for tips but haven't had any luck.

```html
<?php

session_start();

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "california";

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);


 $username = $_POST['name'];
 $password = md5 ($_POST['password']);
 // check to make sure both fields are entered
 if ($username == '' || $password == '')
 {
 header("Location:login-fail.htm");
 }
 else
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='".$username."' AND password='".$password.
 "' LIMIT 1";
 $res = mysql_query($sql);
 if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) {
     $_SESSION['logged_in']= $username;
  header("Location:login-success.htm");
  exit();
 } else {
  header("Location:login-fail.htm");
  exit();
 }

?>
```

Comment: Assign the value from `$res` instead of `$username`

Comment: In addition you should use something like `mysqli` functions instead of `mysql` functions.

Comment: what sємsєм said, plus: you have some security holes. your code is wide open to SQL injections - imagine someone posting the username `'DROP TABLE users; -- `, you should escape your parameter or even better: use parameterized queries - and `md5` isn't a secure hash for some time, it can be cracked - PHP provides the functions `password_hash()` to create secure hashes and `password_verify()` to test passwords against these hashes.

Answer (score 2):

what happens if you add a

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
```

after you mysql_query
and assign the group to the session

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = $row['user_group']
```

EDIT:
I also want to inform you that mysql_* functions are deprecated. Also your mysql query isn't protected against SQL Injections

Comment: That worked! Thanks for your help. I am just starting in learning the basics of php.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use result from db:

```
//...
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $_SESSION['logged_in']= $row['user_group'];
}
//...
```

EDIT: Try to use Mysql PDO instead of mysql_* functions. They are deprecated: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php